# Hibernate TransientObjectException

Tags: hibernate, object, exception, transient

I dont know why it doesn't work ... I thought, it must be able to work through the cascade options in the @ManyToOne annotations.

If its useful: I'm using Spring Data and Hibernate

Any ideas?

```
@Table(name = "lizenzenDistributionstypen")
public class LizenzDistributionstypen {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long mID;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "lizenz", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Lizenz mLizenz;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "distributionstyp", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Distributionstypen mDistributionstyp;

@Column(name = "status")
@NotNull
private String mStatus;

@Column(name = "ablehnungsgrund")
private String mAblehnungsgrund;
```

}

```
@Table(name = "lizenzen")
public class Lizenz {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long mID;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
private String mName;

@Column(name = "version")
private String mVersion;

@Column(name = "url")
@NotNull
private String mUrl;

@Column(name = "status")
@NotNull
private String mStatus;
```

Here is the error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: licenseapp.dbtables.Lizenz
```

Edit:

```
@Table(name = "distributionstypen")
public class Distributionstypen {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long mId;

@Column(name = "beschreibung")
@NotNull
private String mBeschreibung; }
```

And I'm trying to save through the parent of Lizenz

Comment: Please share the code you are using to persist your data , also share the code for this entity Distributionstypen

Comment: The persistence logic too please

Comment: Yes, it is a bit unclear to understand the question. You are trying to save LizenzDistributionstypen by saving Lizenz?

Comment: The persistence is given by Spring Data

Comment: I've got this logic, because one Lizenz has to have five LizenzDistributionstypen.

Comment: @Jonas Could you please update the question to show which method you are using. For example is it persist or save.

Comment: @Jonas I think what you should do is, first add OneToMany relation to Lizienz which keeps the Set of LizenzDistributionstypen. And annotate it CascadeType.ALL. And then before saving it you need to add set of LizenzDistributionstypen to Lizienz and save Lizienz onyl using spring Data. This should be working.